# Node.js / Can two or more instance of my applicaton run with common resource

Tags: node.js

I wrote a server which has a module of [lru-caching](https://www.npmjs.org/package/lru-cache).

In order to avoid single point of failure, I want to run two instances of my server, with common `lru-caching` (So if one instance insert object to my cache, the other will know it too).

How can I do it? Is node.js support it?

Comment: You need to setup transport to some database, like `Redis`

Comment: @monkeyinsight: But then how can I continue to use the lru caching?

Comment: you should extend module to store data in database

Comment: To avoid single point of failure, you need two servers/service on two physical different machines? Then they both need/have a local lru-cache. You can interconnect these machines and write a small send/receive logic that then call the local get/set-functions. Maybe you replace the standard lru-cache-set with your own set_and_send-function?

Comment: @CFrei: It's possible, but this method can lead to race condition. One would delete the file from the cache, when the other try to get this file (and doesn't know that it already deleted). For this reason, I prefer that there would be common caching for the two machines, so the case above can't occurred.

Comment: Then you get a single point of failure: the cache. :) Maybe you just lock that one element that is read/written/deleted?

Comment: Then you get a single point of failure with the cache! :) You either set up the servers as hot standby, then no raise condition can happen or you lock the element?

Comment: @CFrei: Single point of failure in the cache is less critical. In the worst case, I use the persistence storage, and build the cache from scratch..